# Serilog dictionary appsettings in Host vs WebHost configuration

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-hosting, serilog, host

I have two applications(one from `Host` and other from `WebHost`). Both .NET 6. I have multiple Serilog sinks as below in both apps configured in appsettings.json(its a valid json). I'm trying to use dictionary mode of configuring sinks in `WriteTo` section instead of array(see https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#writeto-enrich-auditto-destructure-sections).

In `WebHost` application appsettings are loaded without a problem.

But in `Host` application I get this error `"The configuration value in Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name has no 'Name' element."`
inside `IHostBuilder.UseSerilog(...)`.

What am I getting wrong here?

I have checked with another `WebHost` application and it works. None of the `Host` applications are working.

```
"Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information"
        },
        "WriteTo": {
            "FileSink": {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "ConsoleSink": {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args": {
                    ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```